# Ionic 2 - Debug errors from customer device

Tags: ionic2

My app works fine without any errors in my web and android platforms.

I decided to let my friends test my app, and one of them experience a problem with one of the pages which is not loading for him.

I tried to make a few updates and still, he got issue with that page.

Currently the only way for me to detect bugs is to connect my own device and check them via `chrome://inspect/#devices`.

How I can know which error or problem he experience?

Comment: What if you run `ionic serve` and check in the chrome inspector for errors?

Comment: As I said, in my computer it works fine, no errors. I can't get the errors the customer might have from my debug..

Comment: Sorry @gerdi, it seem like I didn't mention it. I updated my question, my issue is that I can't track errors happen to users who are not me. the app works fine for me.

Comment: you could try [rollbar](https://rollbar.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use bug tracker services for tracking errors from in production applications.
https://www.bugsnag.com is one such option. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have setup ionic 2 to run through a usb onto your android device you can check for errors by prefixing the `run` command with

```
--consolelogs|-c                 Print app console logs to Ionic CLI (livereload req.)
--serverlogs|-s                  Print dev server logs to Ionic CLI (livereload req.)
```

So something like

```
 ionic run android -c -s -l
```

Example of printed errors.

[image]

This replicates exactly how the device will run on the phone. If you are still not getting errors it could be that the user is navigating on functionality that you have not tested for.

Comment: I agree.. but OP has already mentioned it in the question.. I dont think he is asking about this.